# New session is generated for every request inside FB app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-c#-sdk

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 web application, which I would like to publish as a Facebook app also.

When my FB app is visited, my website's specific page (controller+action) is displayed (eg. mydomain.com/Facebook/Index). This request contains a signed_request, which I'm storing in the session.

If I display a link on this page, which points to another page of my webapp (eg. mydomain.com/Facebook/Other), and this link is clicked, then a new-session is generated, therefore I don't know the signed_request which FB passed to my initial page!

**So basically my problem is that the session is regenerated everytime a page/subpage is navigated by the user inside the FB app!**

If the urls are accessed directly (not as a FB app), then my session works properly.

Also if my website is running locally (so my FB app is set up to use localhost:[port], which is hosted by VS), then session works also!

My site is hosted in Azure currently. So if my website is hosted in azure and accessed as a FB-app, session is regenerated in every new request.

I'm not using any FB-authentication yet.

Any advise someone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search terms: third-party-cookies, P3P policy